# How to select between Call and Execution using a Combo Box in AspectJ

Tags: java, logging, drop-down-menu, aop, aspectj

i am currently implementing a logger using aspectj. Now i want to have a GUI from where i can select which one to choose i.e Call or Execution. Based on the selection the AOP will work and log the information.

Is it possible to achieve this? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `if()` in the pointcut definition.

I have created a new AspectJ Project in Eclipse with the following package structure:

[image: Package structure]

MyAspect.aj has the following code:

```
package aspectj;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    public static boolean call = true;
    public static boolean exec = true;

    @Pointcut("if() && call(* *.*(..)) && !within(aspectj..*)")
    public static boolean callPointcut(JoinPoint jp) {
        return call;
    }

    @Pointcut("if() && execution(* *.*(..)) && !within(aspectj..*)")
    public static boolean execPointcut(JoinPoint jp) {
        return exec;
    }

    @After("execPointcut(jp) || callPointcut(jp)")
    public void advice(JoinPoint jp){
        System.out.println(jp);
        }
}
```

And GUI.java:

```
package main;

public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 328, 109);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JCheckBox chckbxCall = new JCheckBox("Call");
        chckbxCall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 MyAspect.call = chckbxCall.isSelected();
            }
        });
        chckbxCall.setSelected(true);
        chckbxCall.setBounds(6, 6, 128, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxCall);

        final JCheckBox chckbxExecution = new JCheckBox("Execution");
        chckbxExecution.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 MyAspect.exec = chckbxExecution.isSelected();
            }
        });
        chckbxExecution.setSelected(true);
        chckbxExecution.setBounds(6, 41, 128, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxExecution);

        JButton btnTestbutton = new JButton("testButton");
        btnTestbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("button pressed");
            }
        });
        btnTestbutton.setBounds(172, 5, 117, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnTestbutton);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps as a proof of concept.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I tried to do it but the once I select the check box nothing happens. I do not get any output of logging. By the way where should I put the code of check box? Is it in the aspect?

Comment: Hi Fred. Thanks a lot for helping me with the functional code. This will help me a lot. However, I want to apply this on external jar files. I want to weave the .aj file with the external jar files which I want to import using the Configure Build Path option in Eclipse. Will this code apply there as well? If so then could you please show me that?

Comment: Could you please tell me where your main method is? Is it somewhere in the external jar file or in your code (e.g. GUI code)?

Comment: Yes the main method is in the external jar file. Thanks